# Communication of express node with python

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, web-services, express

I have an express node application that contains a form which accepts user data , feeds into mongodb and then runs an python algorithm which have user data as parameter and returns data to the application.The problem is that the python code is not running and not returning anything. I'm using child_process to run python code. Please help

```
var express = require('express');
var ws = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var databaseUrl = "localhost:27017/ws";
var collections = ["Users"];
var mongojs = require('mongojs');
var db = mongojs(databaseUrl,collections);
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
ws.set('view engine','ejs');
ws.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended : false}));


ws.get('/',function(req,res){
res.render('default');
});

ws.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
ws.get('/*',function(req,res){
res.send("no where to go..")
});


ws.post('/login',function(req,res){
var user_login=req.body.login;
var user_location=req.body.location;
var user_email=req.body.email;
console.log("User name = "+user_login+", location is "+user_location+",        
Email-id is "+user_email);
db.Users.insert({login : user_login, location : user_location, Email :           
user_email})
var process = spawn('python',['/long.py']);
process.stdout.on('data', function (data){console.log("python script ends  
now..!!!")});
console.log("escaped python");
res.end("yes");
});


ws.listen(3000,function(){
console.log("listening on the port 3000")
});
```

Comment: @HirenS. Please look into it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var process = spawn('python', ['/long.py']);
process.stdout.on('data', function(data) {
    console.log("python script ends  now..!!!");
    // will print process output
});

process.stderr.on('data', function(data) {
    console.log('stderr: ' + data);
    // Error occurred;
});

process.on('close', function(code) {
    console.log('child process exited with code ' + code);
    res.end("yes");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It was a very silly mistake from my side.Thanks @Hiren .S . I didn't put the path of python file correctly.In the above code it has to be ./long.py for same directory.It just slipped my eye.